# Find if next sibling exist

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I try to write some robot test cases and I got stuck. I need to extract some links from a page. The links are stored inside an `<li>` tag which is also inside an `<ul>`. The problem is that after I extract the first link I need to go to the next `<li>` (the first `<li>` next sibling) but how can I find if there is a next sibling without getting an error or the application stop. I know, I can use `Element Should Contain` keyword but in case if it not contain I get an error.
I want to do something like this:

```
if next sibling exist  do something
else go do something else
```

The html should look like this.

```
<ul id="top_menu" role="menubar" class="">
    <li class="menu_accordion_section" id="cat_1">
        <a href="some-exampe"> </a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_accordion_section" id="cat_2">
        <a href="some-exampe"> </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is direct message, you can use execute script to create a varaible.

so i created a keyword

```
  Validate child element exists
```

it takes two argument parent(Webelement) and child(Xpath) to search for child inside the parent.

```
  Validate child element exists    ${parent}    ./h3
```

Assuming parent xpath to as : `//ul[@id="top_menu"]` , the above code will search for equalent xpath `//ul[@id="top_menu"]/./h3` note taht context is parent and not root

so this will be equalent to xpath

```
*** Test Cases ***
Google Search
    [Tags]    you    probably    do    not    have    this    many    tags    in    real    life
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  CSS=[id="introduction-container"]
    ${parent}=    Get webelement    xpath=//*[@id="introduction-container"]
    ${result}=    Validate child element exists    ${parent}    ./h3   
    Should Be True     ${result}

    
*** Keywords ***
Validate child element exists 
    [Arguments]    ${parent}   ${child} 
    ${child}=    Execute Javascript    return window.document.evaluate( arguments[1], arguments[0], null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;     ARGUMENTS    ${parent}    ${child}
    [Return]    ${child}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what is this line doing ```${child}=    Execute Javascript    return window.document.evaluate( arguments[1], arguments[0], null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;     ARGUMENTS    ${parent}    ${child}```

Comment: docuemnt.evaluate is the way to find element using xpath in browser javascript  engine

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate

Comment: This link explanins different argument it takes , in short it checks for the xpath with the parent node as reference

Comment: the keyword return the first child elelment it finds

Answer (score 0):

one solution is iterate over the menu, follow a code example(**this code has not been tested, may need some adjustments**):

```
List<WebElement> menuItens = getDriver().findElement(By.id("top_menu")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
menuItens.forEach(item -> {
    links.add(item.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href"));
});
return links;
```